# Assigning sounds on startup and shutdown

Tags: lightdm

As every time i boot into ubuntu it makes sound, i want to assign a custom sound on startup as well as on log off and shutdown.

Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

If you want another sound during login you can do it this way from a terminal sesson:

```
cd /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo
```

replace the file `desktop-login.ogg` with the soundfile you want. You can do it like this (including backup):

```
$ sudo cp desktop-login.ogg desktop-login.ogg.old
$ sudo cp ~/Downloads/dekstop-login.ogg
```

If your new file is inside your home's Download directory. I have not seen a default application where you can do this.

And yes, you can create a custom sound from for instance a music clip with audacity. Just make sure you save it as ogg and do not make it too long.

You can also do it like this. From command line

```
$ gksu nautilus
```

This will open Nautilus as root. Now navigate to your new file, right click and copy it. Navigate to

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo
```

and click on desktop-login.ogg, press F2, and add .old to the name. Then click on some free space, right click and choose paste.

Comment: one more thing i came to know after exploring /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo  that by default only one sounds is being played for last two months thats system-ready.ogg out of those  , nothing else.desktop-login.ogg and desktop-logout.ogg has never played.Why so?

Comment: see the issue is even desktop-login.ogg is not working .. after starting only drumming tone plays nothing else , no login sounds,shutdown tone nothing at all.